# How to alter the data on the entity default display view

Tags: php, drupal, hook, drupal-8

I have an entity name **packages** and has bundle by name **package**.
I want to alter the value of a field on the view.
I try `hook_entity_view_display_alter(\Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, array $context)`, and change it like this for my case:

```
function amt_general_packages_view_display_default_alter(\Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, array $context) {
  dd($display);
}
```

It doesn't return any thing. How this is possible? is there  another hook to use?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try use hook_node_view

```
/**
* Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view().
*/
function mymodule_node_view(array &$build, Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
    if ($view_mode == "full"){
        // all fields in $build array
    }
}
```